# insert array values in database in php

Tags: php

I get this output when I print_r($new_array);

```
Array
 (
 [0] => Array
(
    [0] => A-I-only

    [1] => B-III-only

    [2] => C-I-and-II-only

    [3] => D-II-and-III-only

    [4] => E-I,-II,-III

)

[1] => Array
(
    [0] => A-Hepatitis-A

    [1] => B-Hepatitis-B

    [2] => C-Hepatitis-C

    [3] => D-Hepatitis-B-and-C

    [4] => E-None-of-the-above

)

[2] => Array
(
    [0] => A)-Cholestasis

    [1] => B)-Cholecystitis

    [2] => C)-Cholelithiasis

    [3] => D)-Hepatic-encephalopathy

    [4] => E)-Ascites

)
)
```

How to apply forloop for inserting options in database.

lyk I have table "answers" having fields "option_a", "option_b"....."option_e"

I want to store array values in database...0 array in first row...1 array in second row..

Comment: Hi you should use mysql insctruction in order to do native PHP insert http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: These are array values...how to insert??

Comment: `foreach($array as $line) { foreach $line as $value { /*  Value to insert = $value */ }  }  ` if I understand your probleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO answers VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

foreach($new_array as $options){
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$option0,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4);

    foreach($options as $key => $option){
        ${'option' . $key} = $option;
    }

    $stmt->execute();


}
$mysqli->close();
```

Code for mysql as requested.  (You might need to add slashes or use mysql_escape_string) if some of the strings have commas or similar. i.e. 
${'option' . $key} = mysql_escape_string($option);
Be aware this is deprecated.)

```
foreach($new_array as $options){

    foreach($options as $key => $option){
        ${'option' . $key} = $option;
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO answers VALUES ($option0,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4)";

    mysql_query($query);

}
```

Comment: no this is not right.. u r not getting.... wht I have written this all is output..i want to fetch array and store options in table

Comment: I guess I completely misunderstood when you said 'How to apply forloop for inserting options in database.'  I created a foreach loop that inserts the options into a database (5 options per database row).  What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: when i  use this statement......print_r($new_array); the above output displays ... multidimensional array....the main array containing 3 sub arrays... now i want code which will insert options of first array (0th array ) in first row(opta,optb,optc,optd,optd)when i  use this statement......print_r($new_array);

Comment: That's why I did two foreach loops, the first loops through the 3 arrays, the 2nd loops through the sub arrays and prepares the sqli insert query.

Comment: The ${'option' . $key} = $option; creates a variable for each option i.e. $option0,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4 creating the following MySqli insert query.
INSERT INTO OptionTable VALUES ($option0,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4)

Comment: simply what i want is....array[0] contains 5 values [0],[1],[2],[3],[4]....i want [0] value to be stored as opt_a,[1] value in opt_b etc...

Comment: INSERT INTO OptionTable VALUES ($option0,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4).... i dont have these values...

Comment: You would need to change the table name to match what your table is called, I made the assumption that the table only opt_a, opt_b, .. opt_e as fields.  The $option0 is basically $new_array[0][0], $option1 is $new_array[0][1].

Comment: If you have more fields in your table you could change the insert query to $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO OptionTable (option_a, option_b, option_c, option_d, option_e) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

Comment: I think you misunderstand my code - $option0 = option_a.  These are generated and populated in this loop for each row.    foreach($options as $key => $option){
        ${'option' . $key} = $option;
    }.  If you don't want to use mysqli, you could change the insert statement, to mysql.

Comment: I've added a mysql version of the foreach loop to the answer as requested.